# How to: access the path of the MSI file in the c# code?

Tags: asp.net, windows-installer

Actually while installing the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer I have to run the console application also, and for that I want the path where I'll be installing the [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer) installer.

Somewhere it is written to use the SourceDir property of the windows installer, and for that it is mentioned like:

> You can use the SourceDir property of the Windows Installer.
>
> You can pass this info as a CustomAction in your deployment project : /SrcDir="[SourceDir]\"
>
> You can then use it in c# with : this.Context.Parameters["SrcDir"]

But where I'll set the SourceDir property?

Answer (score 1):

The SourceDir property is automatically set by the windows installer when you install an msi. You should not be required to set the property manually.

Have you tried reading the property?